# Retrieving Opening balance from Netsuite Chart of Accounts using Web Service

Tags: search, account, netsuite

While I try to retrieve Account details from Netsuite using Webservice, Opening balance always returns null.

I am using the following code to retrieve account details:

```
AccountSearch accountSearch = new AccountSearch();
AccountSearchBasic accBasic = new AccountSearchBasic();
accountSearch.setBasic(accBasic);
port.search(accountSearch);
```

I also tried using port.get(recordRef), port.getList(recordRef[]) and port.getAll(getAllrecord) but got the same result.is there any other way to retrieve the account details of Netsuite using webservice ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This may help

```
public boolean performSearch(NetSuitePortType p_objportCall) throws Exception
{
    boolean status = false;
    AccountSearchBasic l_objaccountSearchBasic = new AccountSearchBasic();
    try
    {
        SearchResult l_objSearchResult = p_objportCall.search(l_objaccountSearchBasic);
        System.out.println(" Account Search Number of records: " +l_objSearchResult.getTotalRecords());
        if (l_objSearchResult.getTotalRecords() > 0 )
        {
           processResults(l_objSearchResult.getRecordList());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.err.println("Acct Search performsearch: "+e.toString());
        throw e;
    }
    return status;
```